# Python equivalent to `as` type assertion in TypeScript

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

In TypeScript you can override type inferences with the `as` keyword

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
```

Are there similar techniques in Python3.x typing without involving runtime casting? I want to do something like the following:

```py
class SpecificDict(TypedDict):
    foo: str
    bar: str

res = request(url).json() as SpecificDict
```

Comment: `HTMLCanvasElement` is a subtype of `Element`. `dict` is not a subtype of `requests.Response`. TypeScript isn't doing any kind of conversion of one value to another, only asserting the dynamic type of a value over its static type.

Comment: Sure, just give it a different annotation.  `res: dict = request(url)`.  Unless your types aren't actually related

Comment: The closest thing Python has is `typing.cast`, which lets you assert (to static typecheckers like `mypy`) that a value of one type has *any* other type you like.

Comment: @chepner my understanding is that `document.querySelector('canvas')` may return either an `HTMLCanvasElement` or `null`, and that `as HTMLCanvasElement` is telling the type checker to trust that you know what you're doing and assume it will not be null.

Comment: `querySelector` has a return type of `Element | null`. If you *know* the returned value will be an `HTMLCanvasElement`, you can use `as` so that the static type of `canvas` matches the asserted type.

Comment: I don't know that TypeScript will allow an *arbitrary* type (that's not a subtype of the declared type) to be used.

Comment: Does `request` actually *return* a `dict`?

Comment: @chepner you are right, attempting to assert `as string` on a function which returns a `number` raises an error: `Conversion of type 'number' to type 'string' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)`. https://imgur.com/a/rDYTVp8

Comment: TypeScript is statically typed; Python is not, though tools like `mypy` will process static type *hints* in a similar fashion.

Comment: @MichaelMoreno chepner's commentary on this has been pretty spot-on, but I think this discussion is sort of missing the point that they're trying to get at: what are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to just get the typechecker to pass (in which case `typing.cast` is a solution)? Or do you want to make assertions at runtime about the return type of `request()`?

Comment: This would be a use for `cast`, because neither `request` nor its `json` method can know that the particular target will return any specific value.  You can assert whatever you *think* will be true using `typing.cast`, but it won't make any difference at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast):

```py
from typing import cast
res = cast(dict, request(url))
```

This will assert to a typechecker that `res` is assigned to a value that is a dictionary, but it won't have any effects at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

`as` allows for explicit casting of a value to a sub- or supertype of the real value. This is relevant for a statically typed language, not so much for a dynamically typed language like Python. The `typing` module lets you provide static type *hints* that a third-party tool like `mypy` can use to look for static-type errors before you run your code, so let's focus on it.

`typing.cast` provides a *general* escape hatch for static typing: you are not restricted to sub- or super types of the actual type. You can *claim* that a value `x` has any type you like, and `mypy` will believe you. For example,

```
x: str = typing.cast(int, 5)  # Sure, OK, 5 is a string
assert isinstance(x, str)  # Oops, I guess not.
```

An `as`-like use of `cast` might be

```
x: Optional[int] = 3
y: int = x  # fail, x might be None at runtime
z: int = typing.cast(int, x)  # don't worry, I promise x isn't None
```

Upcasting is a little easier, as a type annotation will suffice.

```
x: bool = True
y: int = x  # Ok, bool is a subtype of int
```

`mypy` does perform type *narrowing* in certain contexts. For example, if a certain block of code can only be reached if a certain run-time type check passes, `mypy` will infer the type implied by the successful check.

```
x : Optional[int] = 5
x += 1  # static type error, since None doesn't support +=
```

but

```
x : Optional[int] = 5
if x is not None:
    x += 1  # OK; if x is not None is true, then we can assume x: int
```

Comment: I think the "Typescript is statically typed, Python is not" part is a red herring. Typescript's type annotations can be checked by a static analysis tool but are ignored at runtime, the same is true for Python's type annotations. The fact that Python files don't have to be stripped of their type annotations in order to be interpreted is not really significant, and Typescript would still be the same language if browsers recognised the type annotations but ignored them. So `as` in Typescript is very much analogous to `typing.cast` in Python.

Comment: I thought the TypeScript compiler itself used them, so it was a little more tightly integrated than the relationship between the Python runtime and `mypy`. (I know very little about TypeScript, though, so maybe TypeScript's typing is less of a constraint than I assumed.)

Comment: The Typescript compiler does use the types, but not to generate different Javascript code; with the exception of a few Typescript constructs that generate code (enums and namespaces), Typescript is converted to Javascript simply by removing the type declarations and type annotations.

Comment: (I.e., the TypeScript compiler produces dynamically-typed JavaScript code, while `mypy` only checks dynamically-typed Python code.)

Comment: Does the TypeScript compiler produce code even if there are typecheck violations, though?

Comment: `mypy` is just as much a static analysis tool as `tsc check` is - it checks the types in the Python code without running it.

Comment: Yes, `tsc` outputs Javascript code even when the Typescript source doesn't typecheck. Actually it's fairly typical to build TS projects without running the typechecker at build time - `esbuild` and `swc` are popular build tools which do this.

Comment: OK, that was a big assumption on my part.